# Why does this function add a border to all my images?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL.

```
im = im.rotate(angle=-90, expand = True)
```

When I do this, it adds a greyish border to my image.

Why?

Here's m full code. Note that if I don't rotate, it adds no borders

```
def fixRotation(f, quality=96, image_type="JPEG"):
    #http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html
    d =getEXIF(f)
    if d:
        orientation = int(d['Orientation'])
        im = Image.open(StringIO(f))
        if orientation == 6:
            im = im.rotate(angle=-90, expand = True)
        elif orientation == 3:
            im = im.rotate(angle=-180, expand=True)
        elif orientation == 8:
            im = im.rotate(angle=-270, expand=True)
        else:
            #It doesn't add a border here.
            im = im.rotate(0, expand=True)
        res = StringIO()
        im.save(res, image_type, quality=quality)
        res.seek(0)
        return res
    else:
        return StringIO(f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some experiment and indeed image size is altered but I didn't understad the exact behavior. To me looks like a bug in PIL... you should report it.

If you only need k*90 degrees then to do the rotation you can also use numpy...

```
img = Image.fromarray(numpy.rot90(numpy.array(img), n))
```

`n` is the number of times to rotate by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Note the following (CPython 2.6, PIL 1.1.7):

```
import Image
i= Image.open("someimage.jpg")
ir0= i.rotate(-90)
ir1= i.rotate(-90, expand=1)

for img in i, ir0, ir1:
    print(img.size)

# output follows
(720, 400)
(400, 720)
(401, 721)
```

1. When the `angle` is a multiple of 90, `expand` is not needed.
2. `expand` in the case of right-angle multiples seems to activate a bug

So, if all you care about is 90°-180°-270° rotations, just drop the `expand=1` argument; even better, use the `transpose` method (see Geometrical Transforms in the [PIL tutorial](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/introduction.htm) )

Answer (score 0):

When rotating, the algorithm (essentially) averages each pixel with the "next" pixel value. For all pixels "inside" the image, the next pixel is defined. For all pixels at the edge of the image, that pixel is undefined.

So the grey is the average between the known perimeter pixel and an undefined exterior pixel.